# rdfdot : How to set graphviz parameters?

Tags: perl, svg, rdf, graphviz, dot

I use the Perl program [rdfdot](http://search.cpan.org/~voj/RDF-Trine-Exporter-GraphViz-0.141/bin/rdfdot) to transform a RDF file into a svg file. This program works fine but there is no way apparently to specify graphviz parameters such as the graph type ( Which [normally are entered on the command line](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/command.html) ).

For example, we could specify the graph layout: dot, neato, circo, twopi, fdp, sfdp.

So my question is: How can I specify graphviz rendering parameters to the utility rdfdot ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just pipe the output of rdfdot to dot like this:

```
rdfdot $RDF_FILE | dot $GRAPHVIZ_FLAGS
```

I probably won't add [the required feature](https://github.com/nichtich/RDF-Trine-Exporter-GraphViz/issues/1) to rdfdot because piping is more robust anyway.